# Getting file name in text box as soon as i choose with input type="file"

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<input type="file" name="img1" id="img1">
<input type="text" name="file_name" id="file_name">
```

What i want is as soon i choose file in input type="file" i want to get the file name in text box (name="file_name") without any click or submit button. I could not figure out the code for it. Please provide my the code and idea.

Comment: Show an attempt or what you've looked into, and you're much more likely to get help.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it, you can get that on server side  only

Comment: @user1708762  be aware of `Jquery` and its `onchange` function

Comment: @krishna Ya i forgot i think

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  <input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" onchange="document.getElementById('file_name').value = this.value">
  <input type="text" name="file_name" id="file_name">
```

You can add `.split('\\').pop()` to the end of `this.value`, if you want to get rid of the `c:\fakepath`

**Without the `c:\fakepath`**

```
  <input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" onchange="document.getElementById('file_name').value = this.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop()">
  <input type="text" name="file_name" id="file_name">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/4EnRQ/)

Comment: but its displaying c:fakepath/something.jpg. i want only something.jpg how can i do it

Comment: Please use the second part of my answer. `onchange="document.getElementById('file_name').value = this.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop()"`

Answer (score 4):

you can use onchange in jquery like this

```
$("#img1").change(function(e){
    $("#file_name").val($("#img1").val().split('\\').pop().split('/').pop(););
});
```

add this line in `<head>` of html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct3W2/7/)

Comment: it displays only file name and not with the path

Comment: Not a jquery question

Comment: @user3368817 he does not specify in which he want the solution. And also Jquery itself is a javascript. I think you should better know about this before downvoting.

Comment: but its displaying c:fakepath/something.jpg. i want only something.jpg how can i do it

Comment: @krishna Please check the tags in the question. Also Jquery is a javascript framework and you need to include those files. You cannot assume that everyone in the world would use it.

Comment: please read the answer fully. I have mentioned about adding those library

Comment: Why would you suggest the OP to use jquery for something so simple

Comment: and you are trying to say writing two line code is like a hell of job ?

Comment: @user3368817 So what if the question is not tagged with `jquery`? What if the solution can be provided only with it? Do you not answer because there is no jQuery tag? Am a person who does not know javascript well and have to use jQuery even for small things. This answer is also a solution and I see no reason for it to be downvoted. +1

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger thanks. I think user3368817 is so much vexed with jquery for some reasons.so he dislikes it. hahahaha...

Comment: @user3304709 check my updated answer, in future if you want you can use it to get only file which is separated from its path

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I am not against jQuery. Its a wonderful framework. But its utter foolishness to use it just for doing simple stuff like the above question.

Answer (score 0):

The following will show only the filename in file_name textbox.

```
<input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" onchange="updateFileName()">
<input type="text" name="file_name" id="file_name">
<script>

    function updateFileName() {
        var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
        var file_name = document.getElementById('file_name');
        var fileNameIndex = img1.value.lastIndexOf("\\");

        file_name.value = img1.value.substring(fileNameIndex + 1);
    }
</script>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hvqu8/)

Answer (score 0):

This will show the filename using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
  $("#img1").change(function(e){

     var fname=$("#img1").val().split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
     $('#file_name').val(fname);
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/Ct3W2/6/)

Comment: Question is not tagged with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourFileInputNode.on('change', function(e){
    var file  = e.target.files[0];
    // you can get file name from file var and set it anewhere
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" onchange="updateFileName()"><br><input type="hidden" name="file_name" id="file_name"><script>    
    function updateFileName() {
        var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
        var file_name = document.getElementById('file_name');
        var fileNameIndex = img1.value.lastIndexOf("\\");
        file_name.value = img1.value.substring(fileNameIndex + 1);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: change the input type to hidden